# MLE for discrete distribution and finite parameter space

Tags: maximum-likelihood

> One observation $x$ is sampled from a distribution with probability mass function $f(\cdot;\theta)$, where $\theta\in\{1,2,3\}$ and $f$ is given by 
>   $$
> f(i;j)=a_{ji}
> $$
>   where $A=(a_{ji})$ is
>   $$
> A=\begin{pmatrix}
> 1/3&1/3&0&1/6&1/6\\
> 1/4&1/4&1/4&1/4&0\\
> 0&0&1/4&1/2&1/4
> \end{pmatrix}
> $$
>   What is the maximum likelihood estimator of $\theta$?

---

I have read the wikipedia article about 
[Discrete distribution, finite parameter space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood#Discrete_distribution.2C_finite_parameter_space). I think it highly related to this exercise. But I don't see how to go on.

Comment: label the observation-categories (i.e. the values taken by $x$) as 1,2, .. 5. If you observed a "1" what would be the most likely value of $\theta$? If you observed a "4", what would be the most likely value of $\theta$?

Comment: @Glen_b: Thanks for your comment. If I understand you correctly, there are two most likely value of $\theta$ when one observes a "3", right?

Comment: Yes; sometimes MLEs are not unique. If you'd like to write an answer, that could be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Glen_b's comment, the estimator is given by
$$
\begin{array}{ l |c  }
  x & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\\hline
  \hat{\theta} & 1 & 1 & 2,3 & 3 &3 \\
\end{array}
$$